# Handling spam in JIRA

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I have enabled email to Ticket feature of JIRA and any message sent to abc@company.com becomes an issue.

```
This is working as expected.
```

But there are times when I get several junk tickets from a single email address. I guess it creates separate tickets for each line in that mail. I do not know how a single message can create hundreds of tickets in Jira. Is there any way to stop it? Is it possible to filter out junk emails? I do not want to restrict it to the domain of company.com

Comment: Which of the email handlers are you using ?  Each handler uses different rules to create the email.  It would also be useful to see an example of a message that results in multiple JIRA issues being created.

Comment: also would be useful if you can post jira version and plugin version.

Comment: just make sure you read the "Email Preprocessing" section in http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+Issues+and+Comments+from+Email and the service message handlers in http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Services#Services-messagehandlers

Comment: Unrelated to this question, but there is a comment spam attack going on and I used this script to clean our Jira instance: https://gist.github.com/lhotari/caafb4d394412f491861

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We put a postfix server in front of JIRA together with a spam filter (there are a couple available)

if this doesn't suffice, you might

- receive messages into an 'inbox' project.
- when processing the messages you move it to the right project if appropriate.